# Sending data to a table in loops

Tags: html, powershell

I have 3 for loops in my code, each loop will give one column data. I want to send 3 loops data into one table and each loop output should come in column not in row.

```
    $displayname= $ABC| select DisplayName  
    $Name= $ABC| select Name
    $State= $ABC| select State



    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE >  Report </TITLE> 
             <BODY background-color:white;> 
             <body style=background-color:White;>
             <font size=5;color =#f20e2d face=""Microsoft Tai le"">                                              
              <P> </P>                                 
              <Table style= width:50% align=center  border=1 cellpadding=0 
           cellspacing=0 > 
              <TR bgcolor=gray align=center> 
             <TD><B>displayname- </B></TD>
              <TD><B>Name- </B></TD>
             <TD><B>State- </B></TD> </TR>"


Foreach($Entry in $displayname) 
    { $Outputreport += "<TR><TD align=center>$($Entry.Name)</TD></TR>"
    }
Foreach($Entry in $Name) 
    { $Outputreport += "<TR><TD align=center>$($Entry.Name)</TD></TR>"
    }
Foreach($Entry in $State) 
    { $Outputreport += "<TR><TD align=center>$($Entry.Name)</TD></TR>"
    }
```

Comment: Please tag with the language you are using.  Nice first name, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how HTML tables work. To get three columns, you need 3 `<td>` elements per `</tr>` row - you only really need one loop:

```
foreach($Entry in $ABC){
    $Outputreport += "<TR><TD align=center>$($Entry.DisplayName)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.Name)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.State)</TD></TR>"
}
```